# Codeigniter. Why We are using doctrine in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

Codeigniter has its own syntax to write query which return query result in object. This my be silly question but why should we use doctrine in CI? What is the actual use of doctrine? What doctrine does that Codeigniter not doing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly doctrine is an ORM , ORM creates a virtual object database , So you will get your tables mapped as class , entity as object and also relations are 
mapped , so you just dont need to write query any more , It is more felxiable and efficient than Active record query , You should have a good understanding of OOP to use ORM like doctrine , But once you understand you will love it